# In Angular, imported json file as indexed type always return undefined

Tags: json, angular, typescript

You will find instructions to reproduce on your own device at the bottom.

---

I have a basic Angular project I created using Angular CLI, running on TypeScript 3.1.3, with nothing much added aside a class and a json file.

I created a class ResourcesService with the following command with Angular CLI:

```
ng generate service Resources
```

I'm basically using it to load json files, as a mean of localising (instead of using Angular unfinished builtin internationalisation features).

The following is my class, as well as the json file:

ResourcesBundle.json

```
{
    "label.changeLanguage": "Change language",
    "label.education": "Education",
    "label.experience": "Experiences",
    "label.skills": "Skills",
    "label.summary": "Summary",
    "label.language.english": "English",
    "label.language.french": "French"
}
```

resources.service.ts

```
import * as resources from '../assets/resources/ResourcesBundle.json';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ResourcesService {

    constructor() {}

    public getString(label: string): string {
        let resource: string = resources[label];
        return resource;
    }
}
```

Of course, in order to be able to import the json file that way, I've set `"resolveJsonModule": true` in tsconfig.json.

The service by itself is working properly. I can inject it and call the getString method, and it's running without any error.

However, no matter what value I pass to the getString method, the returned value is always `undefined`. I've even tried to hard code the value for `label = 'label.summary'`, but it's still returning `undefined`. The only time it's working properly is when I write the string directly between the brackets:

```
let resource: string;
label = 'label.summary';
resource = resources[label]; // resource == undefined
resource = resources['label.summary']; // resource == 'Summary'
```

Within the TS on VSCode, the content of `resources` is as following:

```
    label.changeLanguage
    label.education
    label.experience
    label.language.english
    label.language.french
    label.skills
    label.summary
```

When using `console.log(resources)`, the console was displaying something like this on Firefox:

```
    Object {
            label.changeLanguage: "Change language"
            label.education: "Education"
            label.experience: "Experience"
            label.language.english: "English"
            label.language.french: "French"
            label.skills: "Skills"
            label.summary: "Summary"
    }
```

So the json is properly loaded, but it can only be used with hard coded string.

The only other solution I found was to give up the json file and initialise an indexed type directly in the code:

```
private resources: { [key: string]: string } = {
    'label.changeLanguage': 'Change language',
    'label.education': 'Education',
    'label.experience': 'Experiences',
    'label.skills': 'Skills',
    'label.summary': 'Summary',
    'label.language.english': 'English',
    'label.language.french': 'French'
};
```

However, I don't think that's a good approach, at all...

In the case of the imported json file, why does it always return undefined when I use a variable? Or otherwise, why does it work only with a hard coded string between the brackets?

---

**Edit:**

You will find below a stackblitz link to a demo project:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2aspf?file=tsconfig.json

If you run it on the browser, it will work properly (the console will properly display `Change language`).

However, if you download it and run it locally,  you will notice that the console will display `undefined` instead.

To run it locally:

- You must have npm and Angular CLI
- Download and unzip the stackblitz demo in a folder
- Run `npm i` in the project folder
- Run `ng serve --open`
- Open the console on your browser, it should be displaying `undefined`, instead of the expected value (`Change language` on stackblitz)

Comment: Can you tell what you are getting in `resouces` of  `let resource: string = resources[label];`?

Comment: @Justcode I wasn't sure of what you were asking for, so I replaced my example to include the `resource` variable, and I added the console output when doing `console.log(resources)`

Comment: Can you post actual data instead of `Object { Object, ... }`? this should be a resources object.

Comment: I tested it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3w7mjd its working fine, there must be something wrong with your resources file or import resources.

Comment: @Justcode I just updated my question. However, the example you gave is my 2nd example: when I initialise the indexed type directly in the code, it works properly. However, when I import the json, it works only if I input hard coded strings between the brackets (like `resources['label.skills']`). It doesn't work if I use a variable.

Comment: very much confusing, can you create demo in stackblitz, so I can take a loook?

Comment: @Justcode My bad, I just checked your example again. And for some reason, it's working... I don't get it. I did exactly what you did. I'll have to try again on my device.

Comment: Create example of yours, so I can take a look

Comment: @Justcode https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uu9lzi It's not very different from yours. But for some reasons, it's working there...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182468/discussion-between-just-code-and-clockwork).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**

According to a comment on the Angular CLI issue, a workaround is to set `"esModuleInterop": true` in tsconfig.json, and to change the import statement from:

```
import * as resources from '../assets/resources/ResourcesBundle.json';
```

To this:

```
import resources from '../assets/resources/ResourcesBundle.json';
```

---

**Original answer:**

After checking multiple times on different devices, I think this is a bug directly related to Angular (current version: 7.0.2).

To take the example I gave in the question again:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2aspf?file=tsconfig.json

On the browser, this demo is outputting `Change language` on the console.

On locale device:

- Download and unzip the stackblitz demo in a folder
- Run `npm i` in the project folder
- If you run with `ng serve`, you will notice `undefined` in the web browser console
- Stop Angular, then run again with `ng serve --prod`. The web browser console is now properly outputting `Change language`

I've opened the following issues for Angular and Angular CLI projects on GitHub for this problem:

- Angular: [Issue #26785: Imported json file as indexed type always giving undefined when Angular is not running in production mode](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26785)
- Angular CLI: [Issue #12781: Imported json file as indexed type always giving undefined, but not when running ng serve --prod](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12781)

Comment: For what it's worth, this is no longer an issue as it was fixed, as pointed out in issue #12781 of Angular CLI. Still, I haven't updated this answer, because I don't want to uselessly bump this question.